# I need to decrease the size of my iOS App

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I have a json file that must be parsed in the beginning of the execution of my app. The size of this json file is 11 MB and the size of the whole application is at 15MB. Is there any way that I can compress this?

```
NSArray *keyOfList;
    _list=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

This is how I access my json file from bundle and parse it

Comment: Zip it! Lib for zipping and unzipping -> https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive

Comment: Compress your json File...